# How do you activate the Curve Tool in the latest version of Blender?

Tags: bezier-curves

I have seen a tutorial on using a plugin for Curves in Blender.
Called Curve Tool.
Doesn't seem to work in Blender 2.74.
What is the trick?

I want to "loft" between curves.

Comment: I tried manually installing the Curve Tool script and it still doesn't show up in the interface. What is the deal?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=loft

Answer (score -2):

I think that you have to be in *Object Mode* to be able to use this. Then, in the add menu the option to add curves will appear.